# Error with UITextField moving

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm trying to design a view within my app that displays an error `UILabel` when the text inside of a `UITextField` does not match a certain regex. Everything works fine except for when my `UITextField` contains an invalid entry and then I tap the screen to dismiss the keyboard. After the keyboard dismisses, the `UITextField` moves on top of my `UITextView` (the red text) and I cannot find out why. I have set breakpoints in my code, but it seems that none of my code is executed after the keyboard dismisses. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Image of UITextField covering up UITextView]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  KeyboardLabel
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var errorLabel:UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var textBox:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var createButton:UIButton!

    var deltaHeight:CGFloat!
    var beenMoved = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register for notifications when the text in the text field is changed
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "validateText", name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: textBox)

        // Add a gesture recognizer to dismiss the keyboard
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard"))

        // Set the text of the labels
        titleLabel.text = "Container Number:"
        errorLabel.text = "Error, Invalid container number.\nRe-enter number."

        // Calculate the height to move the text field and button
        deltaHeight = errorLabel.frame.size.height + 8.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        textBox.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func validateText() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Regular expression for determining whether the text is valid
            let predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[a-zA-Z0-9#]+")
            let empty = self.textBox.text!.isEmpty
            let valid = predicate.evaluateWithObject(self.textBox.text)

            // If the string is valid
            if valid || empty {
                // If the view has been moved down
                if(!self.beenMoved) {
                    // Hide the error label then move the text field and create button up
                    self.errorLabel.hidden = true
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                        self.textBox.frame.origin.y -= self.deltaHeight
                        self.createButton.frame.origin.y -= self.deltaHeight
                    })

                    // Flip the flag
                    self.beenMoved = true
                }
            }
                // If the string is invalid
            else {
                // If the view has been moved up
                if(self.beenMoved) {
                    // Show the error label then move the text field and create button down
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                        self.textBox.frame.origin.y += self.deltaHeight
                        self.createButton.frame.origin.y += self.deltaHeight
                        }, completion: {
                            (flag:Bool) in
                            self.errorLabel.hidden = false
                    })

                    // Flip the flag
                    self.beenMoved = false
                }
            }

            // If the text field is empty
            if empty {
                // Disable the create button
                self.createButton.enabled = false
            }
            else {
                // Enable the create button
                self.createButton.enabled = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are getting into trouble because of Auto Layout.  When using Auto Layout, you shouldn't be changing the frame of your views.  You should create `@IBOutlet`s to constraints which position the views, and update the `constant` properties in code to reposition the views.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks. I solved the issue by creating `@IBOutlet`s controlling the constraints on the height of the `errorLabel` and the top spacing on the `textBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is actually such that initially, the UITextField moves on top of the UITextView if you enter something that does not match the regex.  This is because you are moving the UITextField and button with the following lines of code:

```
   self.textBox.frame.origin.y += self.deltaHeight
   self.createButton.frame.origin.y += self.deltaHeight
```

When the keyboard dismisses, the UITextField and UIButton return to their original locations.  I am assuming you have no constraints on the UI elements.